# Unable to click a delete icon represented in my cart

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here is my HTMLCode:

```
<span onclick="cart_delete('0')">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

I tried with below code:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@onclick='cart_delete('0')']")).click();`

Please help to click on delete icon using Selenium.

Comment: add code trial by you and error as well

Comment: What is the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-trash-o']")).click();

Comment: whats wrong with it Mane ?

Comment: Sorry I was not downvoted to your answer. I know this would be the solution. I just tried formatting code in a good shape... that's it.